# Allowing Access to Microphone in a Packaged Application for Chrome OS Devices

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, getusermedia, google-chrome-os

I'm developing a basic packaged application for Chrome OS devices that directs users to an external website. While on the website, users will occasionally need to use their microphone to read along with the text they see on the screen. Sadly, I'm consistently getting an error message informing me that my media request has been denied.

The error messages appear in two different places and are as follows:

**In the error section of Google's Extensions interface:**

```
<webview>: The permission request for "media" has been denied.
```

**In the console log, after inspecting the Chrome window created by the application:**

```
Failed to connect js microphone. MicrophonePermissionError: Microphone permission denied (navigator.mediaDevices [NotAllowedError]).
```

I have tried granting the appropriate permissions in the manifest ("audioCapture") and including script that listens for media requests made by the webview element.

This is the snippet of code that I used to listen for media requests and grant them when prompted.

**background.js**

```
webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {
  if (e.permission === 'media') {
    request.allow();
  }
});
```

Here is the permissions section of my manifest file:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "permissions": [
    "webview",
    "storage",
    "audioCapture",
    "videoCapture"
  ],
```

I've seen limited documentation on this issue as it pertains to packaged applications, and everything I have seen indicates that I've taken all of the appropriate steps.

Comment: Could you share what is the exact/full error you have encountered so the community will have an idea about your problem?

Comment: Sorry; I have fixed that mistake. You can now see the errors towards the top of the post.

Comment: I'm betting that you need permission.  (These days, the world's all about permission...just ask Joe Biden.) If so, here's a conceptual path to follow: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Could you add a `console.log()` to `webview.addEventListener('permissionrequest', function(e) {` to see if you get the event or not?